# Translation Golf XXXVII - Consider her ways

Tags: traducción, translation-golf

Welcome to a new edition of the game! If this is your first time, there's some info for beginners at the end of this post.

*Consider Her Ways* is a 1956 science fiction novella by [John Wyndham](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Wyndham). It was published as part of a 1961 collection with some short stories called Consider Her Ways and Others (where it forms over a third of the book). The title is from Proverbs, Chapter 6, verse 6: "Go to the ant, thou sluggard; consider her ways, and be wise".

The story is mostly a first-person narrative. It begins with a woman (Jane Waterleigh) who has no memory of her past waking up and discovering that she is a mother of some description, in a bloated body that is not her own:

> There was nothing but myself. I hung in a timeless, spaceless, forceless, void that was neither light, nor dark. I had entity, but no form; awareness, but no senses; mind, but no memory. I wondered, is this - this nothingness - my soul? And it seemed that I wondered that always, and should go on wondering it for ever... But, somehow, timelessness ceased.

The goal is to translate the given text to Spanish, using as few letters as possible, while keeping all the original text's meaning and concepts more or less intact.

Here's a (non-golfed) example translation:

> No había nada excepto yo misma. Flotaba en un vacío sin tiempo, espacio o influencias que no era ni luminoso ni oscuro. Tenía entidad, pero no forma; conciencia, pero no sentidos; mente pero no memoria. Me pregunté, es esta - esta nada - mi alma? Y pareció que me lo pregunté por siempre y debía seguir preguntándomelo por toda la eterindad... Pero, de alguna manera, la ausencia de tiempo finalizó.

- Rules: [Translation-golf rules](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2592/5481)
- Letter counter: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2ermv0rh/2/embedded/result/)

You may want to check past [translation-golf](/questions/tagged/translation-golf) questions to get a feel of the game dynamics and the kind of answers expected.

Want to share translation ideas, ask for clarifications or just tease other contesters? Join us in [La Tertulia](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46061/la-), Spanish.SE's official chat room!

Have fun!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### 127 caracteres

> Sola en un vacío atemporal, ingrávida, sombría, amorfa; mi yo no sentía ni recordaba. "¿Es esto mi alma?", parecía preguntarme in sécula... hasta que se hizo el tiempo.

Aclaraciones:

- *[Atemporal](http://dle.rae.es/?id=4CSrFLq)* = *[intemporal](http://dle.rae.es/?id=LraXAQt)* = que existe fuera del tiempo o lo trasciende.
- *[Ingrávida](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Las39Nh)* = no sometida a la gravedad = no sometida a fuerza alguna.
- *[Sombría](http://dle.rae.es/?id=YKduqpI)* = en sombras. [Sombra](http://dle.rae.es/?id=YK6utrG) = oscuridad más o menos completa.
- *[Amorfa](http://dle.rae.es/?id=2PoFcRh)* = sin forma bien determinada (gracias, [yotanka](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/25714/translation-golf-xxxvii-consider-her-ways#comment42050_25716)).
- *[Yo](http://dle.rae.es/?id=cCEHAgu)* = parte consciente del individuo, que establece la propia identidad.
- *[In sécula](http://dle.rae.es/?id=XQ6JRTs)* = eternamente.
- *[Hacer](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Jwhmcap)* = darle a algo el primer ser.

Comment: no me gusta usar "reanudo", mas bien el tiempo inicio, pero tampoco me parece adecuado, el concepto es muy especifico, en que la "falta de tiempo" desaparecio, algo que sucedio por primera vez, mas bien me pareceria que "el tiempo nacio", o la atemporalidad ceso

Comment: **amorfa** http://dle.rae.es/?id=2PoFcRh quita un par de letras

Comment: @Mike ¿mejor ahora? :-)

Comment: Enhorabuena, eres el ganador! Voy a cerrar esta edición un poco pronto, pero veo escasa participación, por lo que no creo que nadie me proteste y luego me va a costar mucho más sacar tiempo.

Answer (score 2):

148 caracteres de "Español"

> There was nothing but myself.¹ I hung² in a timeless³, spaceless⁴, forceless⁵, void⁶ that was neither light, nor dark⁷. I had entity, but no form⁸; awareness, but no senses⁹; mind, but no memory¹⁰. I wondered, is this - this nothingness¹¹ - my soul? And it seemed that I wondered that always, and should go on wondering it for ever... But, somehow, timelessness ceased¹².
>
> Sin tiempo³, tenebro ni luz⁷, flotó² ⁵. Ni ser, ni nada⁸,  despierta en mi mundo interior⁴ ⁹, ¿en la solitud¹ de mi alma vacía¹⁰ ¹¹? Me pierdo en preguntas, quizá eternamente. Pero no: en nada⁶, empezó el tiempo¹².

⁴ No hay espacio externo en un mundo interior; no hay sentidos

⁸ No un ser entero, pero tampoco nada

Bien. Estoy listo para mi juicio.

Comment: Al parecer "solictud" no existe, es "solitud", lo que te ahorra una letra.

Answer (score 0):

Solo En el vacio,

> primer idea capturada(no habia nada excepto yo, es lo mismo a estar solo en el vacio)

Cuelgo en la atemporalidad inherte de la nada

> segunda idea capturada, Se requiere el uso del concepto atemporal para que la referencia en la ultima idea tenga el mismo impacto y sentido que el texto original

Existente,conciente y pensante pero aforme, insensible e inmemorable

> tercer idea capturada (dividmos los positivos de los negativos para ahorrar palabras)

es esta nada mi alma?

> cuarta idea capturada, usada en el mismo concepto que el texto original, "la nada" es el conjunto de nada en su totalidad, pero "esta nada" habla de la especifica que siente el personaje.

parecia ser esta mi eterna duda

> quinta idea capturada (se pierede ligeramente el concepto que encierra "wonder" y de deambular(wander) en esta idea, solo se mantiene el significado)

pero entonces la atemporalidad ceso

> ultima idea capturada,